# How to create structure with null value support?

Tags: c#, structure, nullable

I'm new in C#. In c# I can't set value of a structure to null how can I create a structure with null value support?

Comment: You almost definitely shouldn't be using a struct in the first place.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason this cannot be defined as a class instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Structs and value types can be made nullable by using the Generic Nullable<> class to wrap it.  For instance:

```
Nullable<int> num1 = null;
```

C# provides a language feature for this by adding a question mark after the type:

```
int? num1 = null;
```

Same should work for any value type including structs.

MSDN Explanation: [Nullable Types (c#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Nullable<T>` which has an alias in C#. Keep in mind that the struct itself is not really null (The compiler treats the null differently behind the scenes). It is more of an [Option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type).

```
Struct? value = null;
```

As @CodeInChaos mentions `Nullable<T>` is only boxed when it is in a non-null state.

[Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

[Boxing Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: `Nullable<T>` isn't just compilermagic. It's supported by CLR magic too. For example a `null` nullable boxes to the real `null`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [**`Nullable<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) for structs, or the shorthand form (?) of the same:

> Represents an object whose underlying
>   type is a value type that can also be
>   assigned null like a reference type.

```
struct Foo
{
}

Nullable<Foo> foo2 = null; 
Foo? foo = null; //equivalent shorthand form
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the "Struct" is not a reference type, you cannot assign "null" as usual manner. so you need to use following form to make it "nullable"

[Struct Name]? [Variable Name] = null

eg.

```
Color? color = null;
```

then you can assign null for the object and also check the nullability using conditional statements.