# How to check an int to see if it is null or has a value

Tags: c#

No all, This is not a dup of this question as listed below in the comments.

[How to create structure with null value support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564682/how-to-create-structure-with-null-value-support)

*This question was asking HOW to Test with using If Then if it was possible...
And the Vb.Net was tagged because i'm sure this happens in vb.net as well.

How would one check in c# if an integer is null:

This was tried:

```
if (INIT_VID == null) 
   {

   }
```

but this throws a warning stating that The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

So how do you test this? Thanks!

So someone asked to see the code... hopefully the negative voters won't go negative vote happy:

from the mvc FORM

```
 <input type="hidden" id="INITVID" name="INIT_VID" class="control-label col-md-2" />
```

in the mvc CONTROLLER

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int INIT_VID,....

 if (INIT_VID != 0) //Added this after finding out that you have to test for zero

 {
 if (INIT_VID != vRS_REQUEST.RES_VEH_ID)
 ...
```

Edit: I guess I am wrong that maybe that INIT_VID is being declared in the public action element...

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: `int` never can be `null`. All value types in `C#` can't be `null`

Comment: int in c# cannot be null. Is this code written by you? You might want to take a look at nullable types in that case.

Comment: primitive type dont have null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create structure with null value support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564682/how-to-create-structure-with-null-value-support)

Comment: Nope Eugene... it was not..

Comment: You've tagged VB because _you're sure it happens_ yet have started on C#. You've now an accepted answer on C# so I can't see how VB.NET is relevant. The do work in different ways however. VB.NET uses the keyword _Nothing_

Comment: Hi Jinx as user asked me to edit to remove the VB... I don't know if it happens in VB.. I just program in VB mainly so I added there just in case someone new an answer to this in VB and then I would just used a converter to push into c#... so I'm not sure about anything sir.. just expanded the universe of help... but it has been removed per a users request... Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/nothing-vbnet). It gives a few examples on checking for VB.NET _nulls_. Basically think of the keyword _Nothing_ and check for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how do you test this?

You don't, and the compiler is telling you why.  `int` is not a nullable type, so it will *never* be `null` and thus the condition will *always* have the same result.

You may be thinking of `int?` (short for `Nullable<int>`), which *can* be `null`.  In which case a test might look something like:

```
if (!INIT_VID.HasValue)
{
    // it was null
}
```

Comment: Hi David thanks.... I am not sure that ! is... is that a typo? Also I do not know what int? is as well. My Value INIT was for INITIAL sorry for the confusion. Thanks... I will look up the ! in front of INIT as I don't know what the represents.

Comment: @mcvdev: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Sadly the .HasValue does not show up in the  autocomplete for that my INIT value...

Comment: If you don't have .HasValue, then it sounds like you have a primitive type... an int.  Which, as others have stated, cannot possibly contain an int.  It will always have a numerical value.  Can you post some code showing where that INIT_VID is declared?

Comment: @mcvdev: `HasValue` is a property on `Nullable<T>`.  If your integer is nullable, it would have `HasValue`.  If it isn't, then it can never be `null` so there's no comparison to make in the first place.

Comment: Oh man.. you guys are speaking latin to me... I have no Idea what a premitive type is or a Nullable<T> lol (Going to look it up though).. No the int is not declared... this was a field value being passed from a mvc page back to the controller... the value in the datatable is an int. I Will post

Answer (score 0):

in C# to be able to check if an int is null it should be a nullable int.
For example:
`int? VAR_NAME`
`if (VAR_NAME == null)`
Then you can check it for null, else you can't, I am afraid.

Comment: Ok thanks Paul... you are also using the "?" I am not sure what that means... I will read up on it thanks!

Comment: Adding ? to a value type allows the variable to have a `null` value, hence `int?` can have a null value.

Answer (score 0):

int can never be null. Instead, it will hold a default value, 0, if not initialized. Thus, your condition will always return false.

However, If you are looking for a nullable integer type, try int?.

Comment: Hi Roee, So I can test for zero then? Wow so How do what happens if you were looking for a value with 0 you would get false positives? IS this a Bug in C#?

Comment: @mcvdev: No, this is not a bug in C#.  `int` has always defaulted to `0`, and this is well documented in many programming languages.

Comment: Thanks David... that is very interesting... I guess testing for Zero has it's challenges...